# Error al crear un proyecto de consola con Net Core desde PowerShell

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, .net-core, dotnetcore

Estoy tratando de realizar el mini tutorial de como integrar una base de datos existente en MySQL Con entity Framework y Net Core.

LINK del mini tutorial. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-example.html#connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-cli

Instale Net Core SDK

```
PS C:\> dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.403
 Commit:    9e895200cd

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19041
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.403\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.9
  Commit:  774fc3d6a9

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

> **Aplicar scaffolding a una base de datos con la CLI de .NET Core**
>
> Inicialice un proyecto de .NET Core válido y una aplicación de consola
> con la interfaz de línea de comandos (CLI) de .NET Core
>
> ```
> dotnet new console –o sakilaConsole
> ```
>
> y luego cambie a la carpeta recién creada ( sakilaConsole).
>
> ```
> cd sakilaConsole
> ```

Lo que yo hago:
Abro mi terminal en vs code

```
C:\Users\MyUser>
```

Me voy a la ruta raiz de mi disco duro

```
C:\Users\MyUser> cd c:\
```

Escribo el comando para crear un nuevo proyecto de consola

```
C:\> dotnet new console -o sakilaConsole
```

Me da este error:

```
PS C:\> dotnet new console -o sakilaConsole
Couldn't find an installed template that matches the input, searching online for one that does...
Usage: new [options]

Options:
  -h, --help          Displays help for this command.
  -l, --list          Lists templates containing the specified name. If no name is specified, lists all templates.
  -n, --name          The name for the output being created. If no name is specified, the name of the current directory is used.
  -o, --output        Location to place the generated output.
PS C:\> dotnet new console -o sakilaConsole
Couldn't find an installed template that matches the input, searching online for one that does...
Usage: new [options]

Options:
  -h, --help          Displays help for this command.
  -l, --list          Lists templates containing the specified name. If no name is specified, lists all templates.
  -n, --name          The name for the output being created. If no name is specified, the name of the current directory is used.
  -o, --output        Location to place the generated output.
  -i, --install       Installs a source or a template pack.
  -u, --uninstall     Uninstalls a source or a template pack.
  --nuget-source      Specifies a NuGet source to use during install.
  --type              Filters templates based on available types. Predefined values are "project", "item" or "other".
  --dry-run           Displays a summary of what would happen if the given command line were run if it would result in a template creation.
  --force             Forces content to be generated even if it would change existing files.    
  -lang, --language   Filters templates based on language and specifies the language of the template to create.
  --update-check      Check the currently installed template packs for updates.
  --update-apply      Check the currently installed template packs for update, and install the updates.


Invalid input switch:
  -o
  sakilaConsole
Console Application (C#)
Author: Microsoft
Description: A project for creating a command-line application that can run on .NET Core on Windows, Linux and macOS
Options:
  --langVersion  Sets the LangVersion property in the created project file
                 text - Optional

  --no-restore   If specified, skips the automatic restore of the project on create.
                 bool - Optional
                 Default: false / (*) true


* Indicates the value used if the switch is provided without a value.
PS C:\>
```

No entiendo porque da el error tampoco me queda clara para que funciona la opcion

```
-o, --output Ubicación para colocar la salida generada.
```

Según lo que entiendo es que cuando cree mi nuevo proyecto de consola y lo va a colocar en la carpeta "sakilaConsole" ?
en caso que este directorio no exista lo crea?
Estoy siguiendo exactamente los pasos que me dicen que realize que estoy haciedo mal?

Comment: La documentación indica, inicializa un proyecto net.core y  una aplicación de consola, y ve a la carpeta recién creada, tu te vas a c:, cuando el comando lo tienes que ejecutar desde la carpeta de el proyecto recién generado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo no tienes instaladas las plantillas, trata usando este comando:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.DotNet.Common.ProjectTemplates.3.1
```

puedes encontrar mas información aquí:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/templates?pivots=os-windows

Comment: Gracias!!! era exactamente eso! de verdad muchas gracias!